# iPhone web app from dashcode RSS feed template works when deployed on a simulator, but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, dashcode

iPhone web app from dashcode RSS feed template works when deployed on simulator but not on an iPhone.

The web app is deployed [here](http://www.alila.se/wordpress/index.html). If I run the simulator and enter that address, it fetches the rss feed and displays it. Everything runs fine.

When I enter the address into my iPhone, same OS 3.1.2 as the simulator, I just get the header part of the page. No RSS feed.

The RSS feed is;

```
alila.se/wordpress/?feed=rss2 

and the source can be downloaded from:

alila.se/rss_feed.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

dashcode is limited. If you are trying to link from another website. it won't work.